# How to make Matlab GUI look more modern

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

The ugly style of the Matlab GUI buttons and everything look like they're from Windows 95, which is a style from 20 years ago. How can I make the buttons, scrolls and the general feel of the Matlab GUI to look less old-fashioned? Is there a way to use the native style of the Matlab software itself and apply it onto the GUIDE?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try modifying default Matlab’s Look and Feel to "Metal L&F" as following:

```
metal_laf = 'javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel';
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(metal_laf);
```

On Windows, MATLAB use by default the "Windows Look and Feel", then MATLAB graphics controls have native appearance.

Also you can try with Nimbus L&F:

```
nimbus_laf = 'com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel';
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(metal_laf);
```

but this usually cause some problems.

A complete and extraordinary guide of the above can be found in Undocumented MATLAB blog:

http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/modifying-matlab-look-and-feel

Comment: Wow, it works well. But I'm wondering if there are any more options other than the metal_laf and nimbus_laf aesthetics?

Comment: Hi, applying the aesthetics seem to have changed in the Matlab software itself, rather than the GUI itself. How can I change the Matlab software interface back to its default state?

Comment: Hi, you can restore default look and feel theme using next lines:


`def_laf = javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName;`
`javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(def_laf);`

Comment: Is there a way to apply the apply the look to the GUI alone? Without changing the look of the Matlab software?

Comment: For other LAF themes check this link: [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40866-jtattoo-look-and-feel-demo-gui](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40866-jtattoo-look-and-feel-demo-gui). Here also is explained how change GUI LAF, without change in main interface.